# look for part of the string and update another column

Tags: r

I have the following data frame and I want to change column B based on the part of the string from column A. So, if C/O A is found, column B will be 1 else no change.

```
df1 <- data.frame(A = c("aC/O A","b","C/O Addddd","d","C/O A","C/O A1111"), 
                    B = c(0,2,3,4,5,""))



     A          B
   1 aC/O A     0
   2 b          2
   3 C/O Addddd 3
   4 d          4
   5 C/O A      5
   6 C/O A1111
```

Note, value for 6 is blank.

The desired result is as following.

```
   A           B
1 aC/O A       1
2 b            2
3 C/O Addddd   1
4 d            4
5 C/O A        1
6 C/O A1111    1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `grepl` to find occurrence of the string and update the corresponding `B` values to 1.

```
df1$B[grepl("C/O A", df1$A)] <- 1
```

**data**

Reading data as characters instead of factors

```
df1 <- data.frame(A = c("aC/O A","b","C/O Addddd","d","C/O A","C/O A1111"), 
                  B = c(0,2,3,4,5,""), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `str_detect`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
     mutate(B = replace(B, str_detect(A, "C/O A"), 1))
#           A B
#1     aC/O A 1
#2          b 2
#3 C/O Addddd 1
#4          d 4
#5      C/O A 1
#6  C/O A1111 1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(A = c("aC/O A","b","C/O Addddd","d","C/O A","C/O A1111"), 
                    B = c(0,2,3,4,5,""), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```